# What are the possible issues with using the collected result in the intermediate operations?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Consider the following scenario where one of the intermediate operations cares about which of the previous operations succeeded.

```
// isSelected -> method that returns a boolean on whether the current source is selected
List<String> selectedSources = new ArrayList<>();
sources.stream()
    .map(source -> Pair.of(source, isSelected(source, selectedSources)))
    .filter(pair -> pair.isRight())
    .map(pair -> pair.getLeft())
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> selectedSources));
```

In this scenario, we are not truly functional, and we are using the result of the terminal collection in one of the intermediate steps. This works, but goes against some of the fundamental principles of java streams, and functional programming in general. Is there any general guidance on whether this is good practice, or if it should be avoided?

Comment: are you actulally trying to find distinct sources and collect them in `selectedSources`?

Comment: Unless you're very bad at naming, since `selectedSources` is empty, `isSelected(source, selectedSources)` will return false given that `source` is not in the empty list, i.e. haven't been selected (yet), so `filter(pair -> pair.isRight())` is also false and filters out the pair, which means nothing gets past the filter. Result: *This code does nothing!*

Comment: Letting the interference aside, these three steps,`.map(source -> Pair.of(source, isSelected(source, selectedSources)))
    .filter(pair -> pair.isRight())
    .map(pair -> pair.getLeft())`, are a long winded way to say `.filter(source -> isSelected(source, selectedSources))`.

Answer (score 1):

Generally using `.collect` with an existing collection is not a good practice. Normally you should collect into a **new collection**.

Although if you still want to modify an existing collection (which may lead to concurrency issues), you can use `.forEach` instead:

```
List<String> selectedSources = new ArrayList<>();
sources.stream()
       .filter(source -> isSelected(source, selectedSources))
       .forEach(selectedSources::add);
```

---

Since you're writing *"not truly functional"* code modifying an existing collection, there is no reason in forcing `Stream API` approach here.

IMHO, enhanced for loop and a nested if statement can do pretty good job in your case. The code is more readable:

```
List<String> selectedSources = new ArrayList<>();
for (String source : sources) {
    if (isSelected(source, selectedSources)) {
        selectedSources.add(source);
    }
}
```

Comment: [Andreas comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61416165/what-are-the-possible-issues-with-using-the-collected-result-in-the-intermediate#comment108653790_61416165) on `selectedSources` initialization and `isSelected` implementation hold true and that was also a reason why I removed my answer to a comment asking clarification rather. This answer would fail for the same reason.

Comment: @Naman As per OP, his code works as expected. We don't have enough information regarding the implementation of `isSelected()` method. I assume it does some empty list handling and other magic under the hood. This is definitely out of current questions scope.